# How to wait on any condition variable?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

`pthread_cond_wait` allows us to wait until a condition variable gets signaled.

However, is there any chance to wait until any of two condition variables gets signaled?

The reason I’m asking is that I have the following situation: I have 42 threads and two possible predicates under which these threads may continue they work. They may continue their work if ANY of these two predicates is fulfilled.

But, but, the problem is, that when one of these predicates is fulfilled, then only one thread, and a specific thread, not any thread, can continue working. If the other is fulfilled, then ALL threads should be resumed.

So, my idea was to have one condition variable that is broadcasted whenever the second pred is fulfilled… and 42 more condition variables, each associated with one of the threads. The appropriate one of them is to be signaled whenever the first pred is fulfilled.

But this requires the threads to wake whenever ANY of a given set of cond variables is signaled… Any chance to achieve this?

Comment: I'd think 43 threads would be the simplest approach:  one thread pool of 42 threads for the massively parallel job and one thread "pool" of one thread for the single-thread job.  Or maybe use a semaphore instead of a condition variable and post to the semaphore the appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only wait on a single condition variable.

However, that is fine.  When a thread is woken from a `pthread_cond_wait()`, it *must* check that the predicate it is waiting for is actually true anyway - this is because waits on condition variables are allowed to be woken at any time (known as a "spurious wakeup").

So, since your threads must check on whether they are allowed to proceed when `pthread_cond_wait()` returns, you can just use a single condition variable paired with `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.  The threads themselves determine (based on examining the shared state protected by the mutex) whether they are individually allowed to proceed or should continue waiting.  So, something like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

while (!this_thread_can_proceed(state) && !all_threads_can_proceed(state))
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
```

---

Alternatively, you are allowed to wait on multiple condition variables using the same mutex (the converse is *not* allowed), so you can have every thread wait on its own condition variable, and then the waking thread either signals a single condition variable, or loops over the set signalling them all, depending on which predicate it has fulfilled.

Which one of these solutions will perform better depends on the balance between "all threads" and "one thread" wakeups in your application.

Comment: Seems like horrible performance. AFAIK switching threads is expensive enough. Guaranteeing O(number of threads) useless context switches… Seems very unclean, even if in the end it wouldn't really matter. Either that, or the definition of cleaness is NeverToOptimizePrematurely and not AvoidExecutingCodeYouKnowToBeUseless.

Comment: @gaazkam: I have edited the answer to provide an alternative solution that does not suffer from the "thundering herd" problem you refer to.